# How to determine this c-lattice parameter using x-ray diffraction?

Tags: condensed-matter, experimental-physics, crystals, x-ray-crystallography

I have an x-ray diffraction data of a single xtal with clear (002),(004),(006) and (008) intensity peaks. I can calculate the c-lattice parameter for each peak. But then do I average them or is there another way to determine the c-lattice parameter for the crystal?

Comment: Are they radically different?

Comment: @JonCuster Actually not. Their difference is less than 1%. So, no need to average? Which peak should I use? The first one or the highest/sharpest intensity peak?